# geometric algebra: dot products of vectors with vectors vs bivectors

Tags: geometric-algebras

The book "Matrix Gateway to Geometric Algebra" by Garret Sobczyk gives the following identity:

$a\cdot(b \wedge c)=(a\cdot b)c - (a\cdot c)b$

Using the identities

$a\cdot b= (ab+ba)/2$

$a\wedge b=(ab-ba)/2$

to expand the proposed identity, including the step, e.g.,
$$a\cdot (b\wedge c)=(a(b\wedge c) + (b\wedge c) a)/2$$
I get $$abc + bca - acb - cba = abc + cba - acb - bca$$
which does not appear to check.

Is there a step I am missing?

On the same page 31 the author writes (equation 2.14)

$$a\cdot(b\wedge c) = (a(b\wedge c) - (b\wedge c)a)/2$$

which is the opposite sign to the basic "identity" I relied upon. Why is there sign minus in this instance? Is not $x=(b\wedge c)$, where x is an element, subject to the identity $a\cdot x = (ax+xa)/2$? There is a similar reversal of sign in equation 2.15.

Thanks,

Gary

Comment: What does the text call the binary operations you notate as a heavy dot and a wedge? Are your two identities simply definitions? [I assume the multiplication on the right side of these is not done over a commutative field; what is the set on which the right sides are computed?]

Comment: Your computation is not correct. For $a\bullet (b\wedge c)$ the factor would be $\frac{1}{4}$, but for $(a\bullet b)c$ only $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

The identities

$$a\cdot b= (ab+ba)/2$$

$$a\wedge b=(ab-ba)/2$$

are correct, but they are only for vectors $ a, b $.  Eq 2.14 from the text:

$$a\cdot(b\wedge c) = (a(b\wedge c) - (b\wedge c)a)/2$$

(with the negative sign), is also correct.  In general, if $ M $ is a k-vector, and $ a $ is a vector, then one has

$$a \cdot M=\frac{1}{{2}} \left( { a M + (-1)^{k-1} M a } \right).$$

I don't know how the Matrix Gateway book derives eq 2.14.  Here's one way to show it, rewriting the dot product as a grade 1 selection (i.e. take just the vector parts of any multivector products)
$$\begin{aligned}a \cdot \left( { b \wedge c } \right)&={\left\langle{{ a \left( { b \wedge c } \right) }}\right\rangle}_{1} \\    &={\left\langle{{ a \left( { b c - b \cdot c } \right) }}\right\rangle}_{1} \\ &={\left\langle{{ a b c }}\right\rangle}_{1} - a \left( { b \cdot c } \right),\end{aligned}$$
however, using $ b a = 2 a \cdot b - b a $, we have
$$\begin{aligned}{\left\langle{{ a b c }}\right\rangle}_{1}&={\left\langle{{ \left( { 2 a \cdot b - b a } \right) c }}\right\rangle}_{1} \\ &=2 \left( { a \cdot b } \right) c - {\left\langle{{ b a c }}\right\rangle}_{1} \\ &=2 \left( { a \cdot b } \right) c - {\left\langle{{ b \left( { 2 a \cdot c - c a } \right) }}\right\rangle}_{1} \\ &=2 \left( { a \cdot b } \right) c - 2 \left( { a \cdot c } \right) b + {\left\langle{{ b c a }}\right\rangle}_{1} \\ &=2 \left( { a \cdot b } \right) c - 2 \left( { a \cdot c } \right) b + \left( { b \wedge c } \right) \cdot a + \left( { b \cdot c } \right) a.\end{aligned}$$

Putting the pieces together, we have
$$a \cdot \left( { b \wedge c } \right)=2 \left( { a \cdot b } \right) c - 2 \left( { a \cdot c } \right) b + \left( { b \wedge c } \right) \cdot a.$$
Finally, note that the reverse of vector is a vector ($\tilde{a} = a$), so if we apply the reversion operator to the last term:
$$\begin{aligned}\left( { b \wedge c } \right) \cdot a&=a \cdot \left( { c \wedge b } \right) \\ &=-a \cdot \left( { b \wedge c } \right),\end{aligned}$$
and then substitute this back in, we are most of the way towards a derivation of eq 2.14 from the text:
$$a \cdot \left( { b \wedge c } \right)=2 \left( { a \cdot b } \right) c - 2 \left( { a \cdot c } \right) b - a \left( { b \wedge c } \right),$$
so after some trivial rearrangement, we have:
$$a \cdot \left( { b \wedge c } \right)=\left( { a \cdot b } \right) c - \left( { a \cdot c } \right) b.$$

You could also derive this from 2.14, using the reversion argument above, since the trivector terms in that antisymmetric sum cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that we are given a multiplication that is associative
and bilinear, but not commutative, then define

$$a\cdot b := \frac12(ab+ba),\qquad
a\wedge b := \frac12(ab-ba),$$

which apply, at least for $1$-vectors, with perhaps some sign
changes for general $k$-vectors. No equation such as
$$a\cdot(b \wedge c)=(a\cdot b)c -
  (a\cdot c)b$$
can be an identity because, as you computed,
the left side is equal to
$\,\frac14(abc + cba - acb - bca)\,$ while
$\, (a\cdot b)c = \frac12(abc+bac)\,$ and
$\, a(b\cdot c) = \frac12(abc+acb).\,$
There is no way to get $\,\frac12(abc+cba)\,$
no matter what scalar factors are introduced.
The proof is by linear algebra using as the basis $$(abc,acb,bac,bca,cab,cba).$$

Comment: The problem stemmed from my erroneous assumption that the expansion of products of vectors extends in the same form to the product of vectors and bivectors. I resolved this with the help of Peeter Joot's book entitled "Geometric Algebra for Electrical Engineers", which is very nice. Sobzcyk's book seems to have glossed over a key point, perhaps for pedagogical reasons. Certainly resulted in my learning the hard way! Many thanks and cheers!

Comment: @GaryLomp Please help to enlighten us about the key point glossed over by adding it to your question at the end. This would help others benefit from your hard won learning!